# Is the Ghoul's consume ability influenced by items?

Tags: werewolv.es

Some items make you appear as killer or user of witchcraft, or have the reverse effect.

When the Ghoul uses their ability on a corpse still holding such items, do they influence the type of action the Ghoul can use? e.g. the Ghoul consumes a villager with a Rune, and gets a role check.

Answer (score 1):

No, check is against the role and its properties, not the player's appearance.